# Firebase JSON Tree Data Retrieval in Swift

Tags: swift, firebase

My Firebase data structure looks like:

[image]

The following code works to update the value of the label to be the current value of `condition`:

```
import UIKit
import Firebase

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    let conditionRef = Database.database().reference().child("condition")

    @IBOutlet weak var conditionLabel: UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)

        conditionRef.observe(.value) {
            (snap: DataSnapshot) in

            self.conditionLabel.text = (snap.value as! String).description

        }
    }
```

I want to update the value of the label to be that of `test2`. I've tried a lot of things, but the thing that made most sense to me was changing the constant conditionRef to:

```
let conditionRef = Database.database().reference().child("test1").child("test2")
```

This didn't work, and I'm not sure what will. I've gone through the Firebase documentation and multiple YouTube tutorials but can't seem to figure this trivial detail out.

Any help will be greatly appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: Note that *let x = (snapshot.value as! String).description* may be an issue as the values appears to be Int types. It should probably be changed to just *let x = (snapshot.value as! Int)* as long as they are int's

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution is to create a reference to the node you want the value of and then observe it with a single event like this:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var ref: DatabaseReference!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
       super.viewDidLoad()

       self.ref = Database.database().reference()

       let test2Ref = self.ref.child("fir-2-b1233").child("test1").child("test2")

       test2Ref.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in
           let val = snapshot.value as! Int
           print(val)
       })
   }
}
```

The key is to ensure you include the entire path to the child node you want the data from.

and my Firebase Stucture

```
{
  "fir-2-b1233" : {
    "condition" : "foggy",
    "test1" : {
      "test2" : 0,
      "test3" : 0
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response! I changed my conditionRef to exactly what you told me to, as well as

    let conditionRef = Database.database().reference().child("fir-2-b1233").child("test1").child("test2")

but my app still crashes with a Thread 1: SIGABRT error, which it doesn't do when I keep my original conditionRef in the question above. Do you have any other ideas?

Comment: @ArjunGupta The code in my answer was copy and pasted from a functional project so it does work. Eliminating that code means the problem lies elsewhere. Possibly a difference in how I define my main Firebase reference and what you have or possibly the root node name. You includes a screen shot in your question (it's better to include text) so it appears your main parent node is *fir-2-b1233*? I've updated my answer to include a complete, working project so you can compare. Note in my structure that fir-2-b1233 is a direct child of the main parent node.

Comment: Thanks so much for your response! It was the String vs Int that was causing the trouble.